How Can I Create Dynamic Base Path In Blazor
I have a blazor application in .NET 8. My App.razor file like below;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />    
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


When running locally, bootstrap files and all redirects work successfully. However, In the test environment, the bootstrap files cannot be accessed because my application opens with an address like test.blabla.com/appname in the test environment.
I am expecting search bootstrap files under test.blabla.com/appname/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css but it does not search in this adress it search  test.blabla.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css so it cannot find.
I tried using <base href="~/" /> and <base href="@NavigationManager.BaseUri" /> instead of <base href="/" /> but it didn't work. By typing <base href="appname/" /> the problem is solved, but this time it gets an error locally. How can I solve this problem?

You can do something like this:
@inject IHostEnvironment Env

@if (Env.IsDevelopment())
{
    <base href="/appname/"  />
}
else
{
    <base href="/" />
}

Adjust the if condition accordingly, like checking your environment variable or other desired logic.

I tried this and problem is solved but there is another problem. When I want to reach my counter page in my local with this link  https://localhost:7021/counter everything works fine but in the test environment when I want to try to reach this page with test.blabla.com/appname/counter I am getting 404.

Are you using specific @page directive on counter component? Can you post a snippet from counter.razor?

My counter page directive is @page "/counter"
